# Stored procedure error with ADO.NET

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a situation here. My stored procedure works exactly fine the way I want in SQL Server.

However, I'm unable to implement the same in ADO.NET.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure bridge_Type(
@EmpID INT,
@Name   varchar(50),
@Mob2   numeric(10,0),
@Email  varchar(50),
@Type   varchar(50)
)
AS 
DECLARE @TYPEID int
Set NOCOUNT OFF

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO dbo.EmpType VALUES (@Type)

SET @TYPEID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN     
ROLLBACK     
RETURN 
END 


Insert into dbo.Emp VALUES (@EmpID, @Name, @Mob2, @Email, @TYPEID)
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN 
ROLLBACK
RETURN
END

COMMIT
```

Here is my ADO.NET connections for simple registration process.

```
public void InsertInfo()
{
        String empdb = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(empdb);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("bridge_Type", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            /*cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", TextBox2.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", TextBox3.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", TextBox4.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Emptype", dropdown1.SelectedValue));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Emptype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            cmd.Parameters("@Emptype").Value = dropdown1.SelectedValue; */

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@EmpID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmd.Parameters["@Mob2"].Value = TextBox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            cmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value = TextBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Emptype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
            cmd.Parameters["@Emptype"].Value = dropdown1.SelectedValue;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Insert Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InsertInfo();
    }
```

Comment: "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."

Comment: It is wrong because this is little tricky.. The dropdown1 value must go to other table.. There a column called 'TypeID' is auto generated which is then sent back to parent table dbo.Emp (EmpType).. I do not know how to do this..

Comment: Your exception handling is throwing away useful information.  Don't create a new exception.  Either re-throw the existing one, or add the existing one as an inner exception, or better yet since you're not actually _handling_ the exception in any way don't bother catching it at all in that location in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you missed a conversion to an int in your @Mob2 parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mob2", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@Mob2"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
```

EDIT:
Thanks to David for seeing this. The last parameter you are adding is called @Emptype, but the stored proc is expecting it to be named @Type.

Comment: It says 'Insert Error:Procedure or function 'bridge_Type' expects parameter '@Type', which was not supplied.'

Comment: What it means is- the dropdown1 value must go to other table.. There's a column called 'TypeID' that is auto generated which is then sent back to parent table dbo.Emp (EmpType).. I do not know how to do this..

Comment: @Girish: You get that error because you're sending an incorrectly named parameter.  In the stored procedure it expects a parameter named "Type" but you're sending one named "Emptype" instead.  Change the name of "Emptype" to "Type" to match the expected parameters.

Comment: Ah, so there were two issues -- the casting error on @Mob2 and the mis-spelled parameter. Don't know how I missed the second one :) answer edited.